# Not getting onActivityResult() from an ActionBarActivity subclass

Tags: android, compatibility, android-actionbaractivity

I am using Android's support lib (android.support.v7) for adding an ActionBar to my app (my Activity extends ActionBarActivity).

I open a contact picker using the following code:

```
Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            contactPickerIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, 999);
```

But I never get to onActivityResult (even after choosing a contact).

I noticed that my startActivityForResult is actually

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)
```

Why am I not getting to onActivityResult()?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If yes then how ?

Comment: Wasn't able to solve it... :/

Comment: Do you start the intent from a fragment?
So yes... Did you call `super.startActivityForResult(...)` in your activity?